# Teechart Mobile - Column3DStacked graph

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

I would like to create a graph that looks similar to the following:
[image]

However I can't find anything in TeeChart that would produce a similar result.
I have tried to create a Bar3D series and set it's MultiBar property to different values but the closest one that I found was MultiBars.None.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with standard Bar series setting the MultiBar property to Stacked, for example:

```
  Steema.TeeChart.Themes.ExcelTheme excelTheme = new Steema.TeeChart.Themes.ExcelTheme(tChart1.Chart);
  excelTheme.Apply();

  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = true;
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible = false;

  tChart1.Legend.Pen.Visible = false;

  Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar(tChart1.Chart);
  bar1.Marks.Visible = false;
  bar1.MultiBar = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.Stacked;
  bar1.BarWidthPercent = 50;
  bar1.Title = "Net personally receivable";

  Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar2 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar(tChart1.Chart);
  bar2.Marks.Visible = false;
  bar2.MultiBar = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.Stacked;
  bar2.BarWidthPercent = 50;
  bar2.Title = "Tax and costs";

  Random rnd = new Random();

  bar1.Add(rnd.Next(), "Do Nothing");
  bar1.Add(rnd.Next(), "Bonus");
  bar1.Add(rnd.Next(), "Dividend");
  bar1.Add(rnd.Next(), "Interest");
  bar1.Add(rnd.Next(), "Alpha Index\nTrades");

  bar2.Add(rnd.Next(), "Do Nothing");
  bar2.Add(rnd.Next(), "Bonus");
  bar2.Add(rnd.Next(), "Dividend");
  bar2.Add(rnd.Next(), "Interest");
  bar2.Add(rnd.Next(), "Alpha Index\nTrades");
```

Produces this chart:

[image]